# AppCenter Android Build Failure React 0.63.3

Tags: android, gradle, appcenter

I am seeing AppCenter android builds to failures with the following error:

```
No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi
```

- React Native: 0.63.3
- Android Gradle Plugin: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'`
- Gradle: `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2-all.zip`

Answer (score 1):

It appears AppCenter depreciated some android dependencies.

Our solution was to upgrade the gradle version from 3.5.4 to 4.0.1 in the root build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
```